# angular-google-maps nemlogging error in ionic

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I get this error after install angular-google-maps library with Bower in my project.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.models.parent due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.models.child due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.utils due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.extensions due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.providers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module nemLogging due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'nemLogging' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Why am I get this error?

Comment: I run "bower install angular-simple-logger" command, but change anything.

Comment: Did you include the angular-simple-logger.js and load the module in your App definition?

Comment: How can I do that? angular-google-maps is already load like this "angular.module('uiGmapgoogle-maps.providers', ['nemLogging']);" I am not using directly angular-simple-logger, its using by google-maps library.

Comment: Should I change something, bower.json, package.json etc.?

Comment: Thank you, my friend, I have to include "angular-simple-logger.min.js" like <script src="lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.min.js"></script> in index.html, it resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @Oliver please make it as an answer. your solution works fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the angular-simple-logger.js-File as angular-simple-logger is a dependency of angular-google-maps.

`<script src="lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3):

You have to install angular-simple-logger as a dependency eg. Using bower then add the js file link in your project.